# How to check if the eventListener is removed?

Tags: angular, events, addeventlistener

I want to remove event listener upon unsubscribing to the observable. My question is how do i check if whether the event listener is removed or not. Is there any way to check if the event listener is remove?

```
export class BroadcastService {

  public events: Observable < any > ;
  public channel = new BroadcastChannel('test_channel');

  constructor() {
    this.events = Observable.create((observer) => {

      const listener = (ev) => {
        observer.next(ev.data),
          console.log("on")
      };
      this.channel.addEventListener('message', listener);

      return () => {
        this.channel.removeEventListener('message', listener);
      };
    });
  }

  public addPerson(person: any) {
    this.channel.postMessage(person);
  }

}
```

And my Component:

```
export class Page2Component implements OnInit {
  private componetDestroyed: Subject < any > = new Subject();
  private xx: any;

  public person = {}
  as Person;

  constructor(public broadCastService: BroadcastService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.xx = this.broadCastService.events.subscribe((e) => {
      this.person.age = e.age;
      this.person.name = e.name;
    });
    console.log("onInit");
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.xx.unsubscribe();
    console.log("onDestroy");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this manually there in your service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class BroadcastService {

  public events: Observable<any>;
  public channel = new BroadcastChannel('test_channel');

  constructor() {
    this.events = Observable.create((observer) => {

      this.channel.addEventListener('message', (ev) => {
        observer.next(ev.data)
      });

      return () => {
        this.channel.removeEventListener('message', (ev) => {
          observer.next({
            ...ev.data,
            removed: true
          })
        });
      };
    });
  }

  public addPerson(person: any) {
    this.channel.postMessage(person);
  }

}
```

Once you subscribe to it, you can check if the data has `removed` property on it.

Comment: can u give me an example , sorry i'm new to angular

Comment: by my understanding this shows that if the observable is already unsubscribe or not. But how do I check if the removeEventListener is executed?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.